# SQL Server: Using CHARINDEX to parse multiplying problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data column that stores products distribution units as 1*1 or 1*2*6. I want to formulate a computed column and have the result of the multiply problem.

below is illustrated example

```
sku       du      computed_du
12345678  1*2     2
12345679  1*3     3
12345680  1*6*2   12
```

Is there a most effective way to perform this calculation on sql server?

Comment: have you considered storing data correctly (as individual columns) and removing the formula?

Comment: i did but i could not, i am working on an existing table ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely something that should be calculated elsewhere, but I have seen the below technique used as a crude product aggregation.

I am not positive about using this for computed column, but here is how you *might* pull it off: Wrap this in a function, schema bind it to your table, and reference it the computed column definition (not sure if mssql will allow this due to deterministic requirement of udf).

Uses split function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor/314917#314917).

```
declare @tab table (
    sku int,
    du varchar(10),
    computed_du int
)
insert into @tab
    select 12345678, '1*2', null union all
    select 12345679, '1*3', null union all
    select 12345680, '1*6*2*0', null

-- 
select sku, du, min(s), case when min(cast(s as int)) = 0 then 0 else exp(sum(log(cast(nullif(s, 0) as int)))) end
from @tab
cross
apply   dbo.Split('*', du)d
where cast(s as int)>0
group
by      sku, du;
```